# updating all form input data in batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, activerecord, batch-processing

I'm trying to figure out why my batch update in codeigniter is not working.

This is my code:

```
<?php echo form_open('about/update_approach',array('class' => 'approach-form')) ?>

<? foreach ($approach_content as $i=>$approach): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?= $approach['id'] ?>">
<div class="admin-group ">
    <div class="admin-form-item">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="128" value="<?= $approach['title']; ?>" required name="title[]">
    </div>
    <div class="admin-form-item">
        <label for="title">Text</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="256" value="<?= $approach['text']; ?>" required name="text[]">
    </div>
</div>
<? endforeach ?>


<?php echo form_submit($dataSubmit);?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

MODEL:

```
public function update_approach(){
        $data = $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);
        $this->db->update_batch('1985_approach', $data, 'id');
}
```

But if I do this, I get the error:

```
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.
```

And if I do a `print_r($this-input->post());`

```
<?php
Array(
    [id] => Array(
        [0] => 1[1] => 2[2] => 3[3] => 4[4] => 5[5] => 6
    ) [title] => Array(
        [0] => CREATIVEZ[1] => CURATION[2] => ARTISTS[3] => PRODUCTION[4] => ENGAGEMENT[5] => RESULTS
    ) [text] => Array(
        [0] => Fromconceptthroughexecution,
        ourcreatorsarethecreativedirectors,
        thecontentmakers and theconversationalists . [1] => Loremipsumdolorsitamet,
        consecteturadipiscingelit . Donecpretiumsemperaugue,
        ascelerisquearculuctusvitae . Inporttitorleo . [2] => LoremipsumIndolorminimmagnaDuisexquieaintempor . [3] => LoremipsumReprehenderitquiautedo utlaborumoccaecatametconsecteturincididuntelitenimeiusmodvoluptatedo aliqua . [4] => LoremipsumExercitationestdolorminimdoloreadidnonlaborismollitExcepteurnostrudexadipisicingdoloreculpa . [5] => LoremipsumNoneaetvelitaliquipsedculpadoloranimdolormagnaintemporid .
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't use Code Igniter in a long time. 
I checked the documnentation and what you find there is this:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

You do have the right data, but the false structure. Convert the data to:

```
array(
    array(
          'id'=>1,
          'title'=>'CREATIVEZ',
          'text'=>'some text'
         ),
    array(
          'id'=>2,
           title'=>'CURATION',
           'text'=>'some text'
         )
 );
```

In PHP you often use the associative arrays instead of traditional objects.
So think of the the single entries of the php array as traditional objects.